# I'm trying to convert some python code to C#, what is this array syntax?

Tags: python, c#, arrays

I'm trying to convert a few lines of code in python that I'm converting to C#.

In the C# version, I'm stumped with the list/array syntax that begins with the heatmap_center variable.

In the fragment below, what is the purpose of the heatmap_with_borders variable?

This is the python fragment:

```
def extract_keypoints(heatmap, all_keypoints, total_keypoint_num):
    heatmap[heatmap < 0.1] = 0
    heatmap_with_borders = np.pad(heatmap, [(2, 2), (2, 2)], mode='constant')
    heatmap_center = heatmap_with_borders[1:heatmap_with_borders.shape[0]-1, 1:heatmap_with_borders.shape[1]-1]
    heatmap_left = heatmap_with_borders[1:heatmap_with_borders.shape[0]-1, 2:heatmap_with_borders.shape[1]]
    heatmap_right = heatmap_with_borders[1:heatmap_with_borders.shape[0]-1, 0:heatmap_with_borders.shape[1]-2]
    heatmap_up = heatmap_with_borders[2:heatmap_with_borders.shape[0], 1:heatmap_with_borders.shape[1]-1]
    heatmap_down = heatmap_with_borders[0:heatmap_with_borders.shape[0]-2, 1:heatmap_with_borders.shape[1]-1]

    heatmap_peaks = (heatmap_center > heatmap_left) &\
                    (heatmap_center > heatmap_right) &\
                    (heatmap_center > heatmap_up) &\
                    (heatmap_center > heatmap_down)
    heatmap_peaks = heatmap_peaks[1:heatmap_center.shape[0]-1, 1:heatmap_center.shape[1]-1]
    keypoints = list(zip(np.nonzero(heatmap_peaks)[1], np.nonzero(heatmap_peaks)[0]))  # (w, h)
    keypoints = sorted(keypoints, key=itemgetter(0))

    suppressed = np.zeros(len(keypoints), np.uint8)
    keypoints_with_score_and_id = []
    keypoint_num = 0
    for i in range(len(keypoints)):
        if suppressed[i]:
            continue
        for j in range(i+1, len(keypoints)):
            if math.sqrt((keypoints[i][0] - keypoints[j][0]) ** 2 +
                         (keypoints[i][1] - keypoints[j][1]) ** 2) < 6:
                suppressed[j] = 1
        keypoint_with_score_and_id = (keypoints[i][0], keypoints[i][1], heatmap[keypoints[i][1], keypoints[i][0]],
                                      total_keypoint_num + keypoint_num)
        keypoints_with_score_and_id.append(keypoint_with_score_and_id)
        keypoint_num += 1
    all_keypoints.append(keypoints_with_score_and_id)
    return keypoint_num
```

I've barely started the C# version, not focused on the np.pad bit for now.

```
private static int extractKeypoints(NDArray heatmap, List<float> all_keypoints_by_num, int total_keypoints_num)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < heatmap.size; i++)
            {
                if (heatmap[i] < 0.1)
                    heatmap[i] = 0;
            }

        }
```

Comment: solution: 1. find out what np.pad is (quick google "np.pad" - part of numpy) 2. search for C# library which has same functions 3. use it ... **edit:** wait ... `NDArray` seems to be from this library ... so where is the problem?

Comment: I don't need help with np.pad. It's the way heatmap_center is being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np.pad seems to be adding a 2 'pixel' border around the whole heatmap.  So if the heatmap is 124x124, the result will be a 128x128 heatmap.

Now let's simplify

```
heatmap_center = heatmap_with_borders[1:heatmap_with_borders.shape[0]-1, 1:heatmap_with_borders.shape[1]-1]
```

we'll start with

```
heatmap_with_borders[1:heatmap_with_borders.shape[0]-1
```

`1:heatmap_with_borders.shape[0]-1` means pull the items from 1 to the size of the dimension -1

in our 128,128 example, the dimension is going to be 128  so we're saying: **from 1 to 127**

so simplified concretely

```
heatmap_center = heatmap_with_borders[1:127, 1:127]
```

So your just skipping the outer 1 'pixel' of the 2 pixel border.  in C#, there is no native 'pull part of the list' syntax, so you'll need a method like

```
getSublist(heatmap, start1, end1, start2, end2)
```

and so your calls will look like

```
heatmap_center = getSublist(heatmap, 1, heatmap.Length - 1, 1, heatmap[0].Length -1)
```

My suggestion is if you care at all about C# to implement this yourself, to get comfortable working with it in C#, then if the speed is too slow, find a library with similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Really helps. I'm down a rabbit hole, essentially trying to get this project to work over in C# land: https://github.com/Daniil-Osokin/lightweight-human-pose-estimation-3d-demo.pytorch

Comment: @Irwin yeah I didn't realize you were already a c# dev, so I'm sure you'll have no problem implementing this.  And this is a great example of why python is so popular for this kind of work.  Basically if you're wondering whether doing stuff like this in python is worth it, look no further than this example. if the lists don't impress you, you'll find precious little else in python worth the switch..

Answer (score 0):

As to your specific question "In the fragment below, what is the purpose of the heatmap_with_borders variable?"

It seems that it adds a 2 'pixel' border.  The algorithm seems to make some kind of heatmap based on neighboring pixels. Let's say it takes 1 pixel offset crops and seeing which is greater, the center or the 1 pixel crop. So the border is there to 'pad' the heatmap so as to keep all the slight 'crops' the same size and in bounds.